# how to storing data in wago pfc200

Tags: plc, wagon

we have got a new WAGO 8202 PLC.
I know that we can store process data in CSV file using CSV Utility, but CSV isn't good choice for our purpose.

What is the best way to store process data in PLC (SQLLite or some embeded database) during loss of network and re transmit them to historical server or SQL Server?

Can we write a program in CodeSys to check connection with Server based on intervals and resend process data which is unsent ? is there a library or module to facilitate this?

Comment: how much process data are you looking to store?

Comment: @mrsargent,  data for power outage period, for example, 12 hours with 2 minute interval

Comment: how much data is that?  can you store in NV memory?

Comment: i think at maximum it should something about 100MB